# How to append to a nested array in a JSON column postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have column with the next structure:

```
 {
  "_id": "57101c4efbea42d219e068b3",
  "name": "System admin group",
  "is_service": 0,
  "security_lists": {
    "actions": [
      "ota upload",
      "widgets manage",
      "scheduled jobs manage all",
      "users view"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I append value to actions array?
I suppose that it's can be done using jsonb_set() but I can't figure out how to do it(

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE 
        group_permissions 
    SET 
        "document"=jsonb_set("document"::jsonb, 
        '{security_lists, actions}', 
        ("document" ->'security_lists'->'actions')::jsonb || 
        '["newString"]'::jsonb) 
    WHERE 
        "document"::json->>'name'='System admin group';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).